# How would I recover a crashed Windows 7 instance running in VMware Player?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

I run a VMware Workstation 9.0 VM (Windows 7 x64) on a Windows XP (32bit) host on i7 hardware in free VMware Player. This VM had dedicated only 1GB memory and run accordingly slow with a lot of swapping. After changing memory to 2 GB and restarting, the Player told me "A raw disk is detected" and Windows 7 does not start anymore.

Any suggestions how to repair this?

Answer (score 1):

Jump to "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VMware\VMware Workstation"

## Save copy .vmdk

Run:

Check a sparse virtual disk for consistency and attempt to repair any errors:

```
vmware-vdiskmanager -R <You Virtual HDD name>.vmdk
```

If need convert to old vmdk:

```
vmware-vdiskmanager -r <You Virtual HDD name>.vmdk -s <size>Gb -t 6 <Convert Old type HDD name>.vmdk
```

`-t 6` - thin provisioned virtual disk - ESX 3.x and above

may be help ...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But this didn't work for me.

Comment: @esc1729 Possible to see the full text of the error or a screenshot? Maybe it's better to clarify the situation and perhaps there would be more answers and actions.

Comment: Thank you everybody! I've got it running finally. Reason for the problem obviously was that I had dedicated a disk partition (externally of the VM) for the Windows swap file which worked with my initial setup but didn't survive the upgrade to VMware Workstation 9.0. Perhaps because it was not mounted in the host, only in the VM. When I removed this partition from the VM Windows 7 booted again.

Comment: @esc1729 Thank you for highlighting ways to solve the problem!